# inside dimension for homemade digestive cookie mold

Tags: baking

I'm interested in modeling and 3D printing a digestive cookie mold in metal. I plan to model some text into the press itself, so that the cookie's all have a consistent wordmark after baking. Since I have never baked these before, I don't know how thick they should be before baking (ie how deep the mold should be) and I'm thinking if I make the letterforms too thin, the text won't be readable in the event that the batter swells up when baked and fills in the gaps.

Do any of you seasoned bakers have any suggestions for how deep the press needs to be, and how best to model the letterforms? Thank you!

Comment: The are decorative cookie sheets to copy.   http://www.wilton.com/6-cavity-non-stick-heart-cookie-pan/2105-1068.html  Google decorative cookie shaped pan

Answer (score 5):

The dough used in a mold has a lot to do with the end result. It's best to use a firm, non-sticky dough, that can be gently pressed into the mold to imprint the design.  Commercial digestives are not baked in a mold, but are machine embossed and cut before baking, using a rotary mold that incises the distinctive design (e.g., Digestives, Oreo). For your biscuits, you might consider creating a stamp or, if you're really ambitious, a rolling pin version.

Here's an example of a stamp sold at Jarrold (UK)

[image]
And a commercial roller manufactured by F&S Engraving (Mount Prospect, Illinois US)
[image]